# How to suppress the error {Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "*"}

Tags: replace

I want to  alter existing files automatically,to replace all tab with four blanks in existing file.

```
vim .gvimrc
autocmd BufRead  *  exec "%s/\t/    /g"
```

The error info pop up when to open a file without tab key in it.

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "*":
E486: Pattern not found: ^I
E486: Pattern not found: ^t
```

How to suppress the error info ?
Issue remain according to Naumann's answer.

```
autocmd BufRead  *  %s/\t/   /ge
```

Please watch the avi.
[issue remain](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uroznee7q1m567z/out.avi)

Comment: are you sure, that is the autocommand that causes your issue? You do not have a similar autocommand in other startup files? Check the output of `:verbose :au BufRead *`

Answer (score 1):

First: you don't need `exec` here.

Use the `/e` flag to avoid error messages, as in `autocmd BufRead  *  %s/\t/   /ge`

This flag is described in [`:help :s_e`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3As_e)

Comment: Please watch my avi ,issue remain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace tabs with spaces in your file you could also use [`:retab`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:retab).  It also depends on the options `'et'` and `'ts'`.

The advantage should be that you do not replace every tab with four spaces but only so many as are needed to fill the width of `'ts'`.

Answer (score 0):

Will adding `:silent!` work?

```
autocmd BufRead  *  silent! %s/\t/   /ge
```

You'll need to use `:silent!`, as `:silent` only removes normal messages (and only up to the first error).